# "<HTMLImageElement> has no method" error for an object that appears to exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using Chrome and the build in developer tools. What I do the following in the console

```
$('.votes > a > img')[0]
```

I get this

```
<img src="/myimage_png">
```

But if I do

```
$('.votes > a > img')[0].get(0).tagName
```

I get

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'get'
```

I don't understand why sometimes I'm able to do `.get(0).tagName` and sometimes I'm not (depending on what my selector is of course)

Comment: Use either `[0]` or `.get(0)`, not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.get()` retrieves a specified DOM element from a list of elements. the `$('.votes ...')` stuff call returns such an element list. You dereference this list with `[0]`, fetching the first of the found nodes. That means you're no longer working with a DOMNode list, you're working with a DOMElement, and a DOMElement has no `.get()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The numberical indexer of a jQuery object (using `[0]`) will return the DOM element that is at that position in the jQuery results array.

In your example of

```
$('.votes > a > img')[0].get(0).tagName
```

What you're doing is using the indexer to get back the DOM element then attempting to use the `get` method against it.

Using the indexer or `get` will result in the same thing as they both return the DOM element at a particular point in the jQuery results array (the only main difference is `get()` with no arguments returns only the DOM elements).